# How to fill the gaps in a list of tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, indexing, tuples

I have a list of tuples like the following:

```
[(1, 'Red'), (2, 'Yellow'), (6, 'Pink'), (7, 'Blue'), (8, 'Green')]
```

The numbers in the tuple represent the index. However, since some of the indexes are missing in my input file, i need to insert some tuples in the list, and make the list look like the following:

```
[(1, 'Red'), (2, 'Yellow'), (3, None), (4, None), (5, None), (6, 'Pink'), (7, 'Blue'), (8, 'Green')]
```

If some of you have any ideas I would really appreciate if you take your time and comment something.

Comment: that doesn't look like valid python

Comment: Can you share a *valid list*?

Comment: *Updating tuples* is by definition not possible. *Inserting values—which may be tuples—into a list* on the other hand is pretty trivial. What problem do you have doing so?

Comment: You can't update the value of a tuple, but you can _replace_ them if they're stored in a list or other mutable container.

Comment: [(1, 'Red'), (2,  'Yellow'), (6,  'Pink'), (7,  'Blue'), (8,  'Green')]  that is the original list, and this is what i expect:  [(1,'Red'), (2,'Yellow'), (3, None), (4, None), (5, None), (6, 'Pink'), (7, 'Blue'), (8, 'Green')

Comment: I've updated the question with valid Python :)

Comment: @martineau my problem is that i need to insert the tuples, which should contain the index numbers missing from the original list, in this case 4, 5 , 6

Comment: Yes... Voted to reopen.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is your list always sorted by index? Do you need to modify the list inlace, or is it fine to create a new list from the old one?

Comment: Its fine to create a new one as well. What i tried was to use the index() function of the list and then assign it to each tuple, but the problem was that it was returning index = 3 for all the missing tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose here the simplest implementation, but not very efficient for large lists:

```
test = [(1, 'color: Red'), (2, 'color: Yellow'), (6, 'color: Pink'), (7, 'color: Blue'), (8, 'color: Green')]


max_index = max(test, key=lambda item:item[0])[0]

missing_values = []
for i in range(1, max_index + 1):
    missing = False
    for index, val in test:
        if i != index:
            missing = True
        else:
            missing = False
            break
    if missing:
        missing_values.append((i,'color: None'))

new_test = test + missing_values
new_test_sorted = sorted(new_test, key=lambda x:x[0])
print(new_test_sorted)
```

That gives:

```
[(1, 'color: Red'), (2, 'color: Yellow'), (3, 'color: None'), (4, 'color: None'), (5, 'color: None'), (6, 'color: Pink'), (7, 'color: Blue'), (8, 'color: Green')]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you pls tell me what happens in the line list_items = lambda test : test[0]

Comment: Absolutely nothing! It Is a typo! I Will remove It now ^_^

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple approach you can try out. If first gets the `min` and `max` number range, then gets the missing numbers using set difference `set(A) - set(B)`, then concatenates the missing numbers with original list and sorts the result with [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted). I've added comments to explain the approach as well :)

```
lst = [(1, 'Red'), (2, 'Yellow'), (6, 'Pink'), (7, 'Blue'), (8, 'Green')]

# Get only numbers
active_numbers = [x for x, _ in lst]

# Get min and max ranges
min_number, max_number = min(active_numbers), max(active_numbers)

# Get all possible numbers in range
all_numbers = set(range(min_number, max_number + 1))

# Find missing numbers using set difference set(A) - set(B)
difference = all_numbers - set(active_numbers)

# Add missing numbers and original numbers and sort result
result = list(sorted(lst + [(x, None) for x in difference]))

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 'Red'), (2, 'Yellow'), (3, None), (4, None), (5, None), (6, 'Pink'), (7, 'Blue'), (8, 'Green')]
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that either the list is sorted or that the result doesn't need to preserve the list order, you can use a `dict` created from the original list.

```
z = [(1, 'Red'), (2, 'Yellow'), (6, 'Pink'), (7, 'Blue'), (8, 'Green')]
d = dict(z)
low, high = min(d), max(d)
result = [(i, d.get(i)) for i in range(low, high + 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked for me. It's very naive and not particularly efficient. 
The `min_key` and `max_key` give you the interval bounds for your keys, so you don't always start as 0. For all indices in that range, it will set a default value of `None`. If a value is present, nothing is changed.

Then, the items in the dictionary will be sorted based on the key value.

```py
    data = [(1, 'Red'), (2, 'Yellow'), (6, 'Pink'), (7, 'Blue'), (8, 'Green')]
    data_as_dict = dict(data)
    max_key = max(data_as_dict.keys())
    min_key = min(data_as_dict.keys())

    for i in range(min_key, max_key):
        data_as_dict.setdefault(i, None)
    data_as_dict = sorted(data_as_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[0])
    print(data_as_dict)
```

```py
[(1, 'Red'), (2, 'Yellow'), (3, None), (4, None), (5, None), (6, 'Pink'), (7, 'Blue'), (8, 'Green')]
```

However, if you don't mind starting at index 0, you might want to have a look at using a list containing just your colours, where the first value of your tuple is the index inside the list, to optimise the memory footprint.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple,one-pass method that keeps the orig order:

```py
out = []
lasti = 0
for i, v in data:
    if i - lasti > 1:
        # if not continued, fix the gap
        for j in range(lasti + 1, i):
            out.append((j, None))
    out.append((i, v)) # add the value
    lasti = i
print(out)
```

**Output:**

```py
[(1, 'Red'), (2, 'Yellow'), (3, None), (4, None), (5, None), (6, 'Pink'), (7, 'Blue'), (8, 'Green')]
```